# My brake pedal is stuck

Tags: brakes, dodge, charger

I was driving my 2006 Daytona Charger the other day and the brake pedal started to stiffen up. I got home and pulled up in the driveway, pressed the brake pedal in to put the car in park. The brake pedal just stuck all the way at the bottom. I cannot even force the pedal back up with my foot. It is just stuck to the floor. Please help.